# How to avoid "The operation is insecure" error when accesing opened window

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to open a new window and fill it with data ready to be copyed in clipboard, printed or saved to hard drive. I'm doing this through **Greasemonkey user script**.

Simplified version of the script:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  /*EXPORT DATA*/
  //Create a button
  var button = document.createElement("input");
  //call the actual export function 
  button.onclick = function() {window.exportujRozvrh();};
  //I also tried this:
    //button.onclick = (function() {window.exportujRozvrh();}).bind(window);

  button.value = "Print data in new tab";
  button.type = "button"; 
  //Append button to a node
  getElementByXpath(tisk_path).appendChild(button);
});


   window.exportujRozvrh = function() {
      //create a new tab (or window if tab not supported)
      var okno = window.open(); //No url should be fine for same origin policy, shouldn't it?
      //check if popup exists
      if(okno==null)
        alert("Popup blocked.");
      //Write the data
      okno.document.open();
      okno.document.write("data"); 
      okno.document.close();
   }
```

If run from `button` this function throws following error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

However, if the function is lauhced from debug console <del>or from URL bar (by typping `javascript: window.exportujRozvrh();void(0)`)</del><sup>1)</sup> the script works properly.
So I guess it's the context this function is launched in matters. That why I was trying to use `.bind(window)`.

<sup>**1)** calling this throws "window is not defined" error. I'm quite used to the fact that window is always defined, so I gave this up.</sup>

Comment: Do you need to attach the function to `window`?

Comment: Yeah, because variables defined in greasemonkey script are not global.